# Proper way to dynamically add MaterialJS Buttons

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I am trying to dynamically add AngularJS Material buttons, "md-button", to certain elements on a page. I have tried using a jQuery.append option but the button never renders though the text appears.

```
    $scope.toggleChecked = function (item) {
        $("#checkedItems").append('<md-button class="md-raised md-primary">'+item+'</md-button>');
        var index = $scope.checked.indexOf(item);
        if (index == -1) {
            $scope.checked.push(item);
        } else {
            $scope.checked.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
```

What is the best way to handle adding new buttons to a DIV or SPAN?

Plunker: http://jsfiddle.net/odgma1w6/

https://material.angularjs.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to manipulate DOM in Angularjs is to use **directives**.

At first you need to create directive:

```
angular.module('home').directive('addButtonDirective', ['$log', addButtonDirective]);

function addButtonDirective($log) {
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, element, attributes) {
                var el = $(element);

                el.append('<md-button class="md-raised md-primary md-button md-default-theme">test</md-button>');
            }
        }
};
```

And add it to your HTML like this:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="fruit in fruits | filter:searchText" add-button-directive>
```

I have updated you jsfiddle, check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/odgma1w6/1/

Comment: That's using an ng-repeat which is not what i am trying to do. I'm trying to inject a button into a span.